# Oracle Index pick up

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, query-performance, sql-execution-plan

All,

I am facing a peculiar issue in Oracle for following scenario.

```
View A - Column 1 - 5
Table B - Column 1, 2, 6-10 (Has millions of Rows)
```

Common columns between View A and Table B are Column 1 & 2.

Table B has index on Column 1, 2.

Query goes like this

```
SELECT vw.column3, vw.column4, vw.column5, tbl.column2, tbl.column6... tbl.column10
  from viewA vw
  join tableB tbl
    on tbl.column1 = vw.column1
       and tbl.column2 = vw.column2
```

though i am joining on the index available on the table, query is doing a full scan on the table instead of index scan. Please help understand this issue.

TABLE ANALYZED, NO HISTOGRAM, TRIED HINTING by specifying the index in the query as well.

Comment: Is there some reason to believe that using the index on B would be beneficial?  Is there some reason to believe that view A will return a small subset of the `column1, column2` values that are in the table B?  It appears (naively) that a table scan would be the most efficient approach unless there are some pretty selective predicates that you haven't mentioned.

Comment: Since the table has millions of records query result taking longer time and i assume if the query could use the index, it might be faster..

Comment: What leads you to believe that? You have no WHERE clause to tell the database how you'd like to subset the data, and you're accessing fields which are not on the index; thus, if the database chooses to use the index it has to read the index, THEN it has to turn around and read the table anyway. From the point of view of the database it's more efficient to read only the table.

Comment: Actually, there's not enough information here to make a determination either way.  It's possible that there's only one row coming out of the view, and joining to the table reduces the output of the entire query to one row.  But, we don't know that, cause we don't know how many rows the view produces, or what access path it uses to achieve it's result set.

Comment: Please post an explain plan of this query (first run: `EXPLAIN PLAN FOR the_query`, then `SELECT * FROM table(DBMS_XPLAN.Display)` and then copy-paste the output of the last command). Please also give an information what kind of indexes do you have - for now we only know that you are joining on `avaliable indexes`, but we don't know more details.

Comment: @BobJarvis - I got your point.. Thanks for Clarifying.. so question now would be is there any better way to make that query perform better.. any index or anything could be done with the current scenario to make it better not from query tuning perspective but from table front.

Comment: All, its a inline query view not a physical view on the DB.

Comment: Does the view (inline or otherwise) return a sufficiently small subset of `column1, column2` values from B that it might make sense to use an index?  Or do you have a query that is going to return millions of rows because you don't have any filter predicates?  Oracle seems to be guessing the latter and you're not telling us otherwise.

Comment: @JustinCave - inline view does return small subset of column 1 & 2

Comment: OK, how small a subset?  Table B has millions of rows.  Should the join return a few thousand rows?  Now that you're providing some reason to believe that an index might be beneficial, posting a query plan along with the actual selectivity estimates would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Whether Oracle should use the index OR not depends on many factors.

i) Indexes are meant to provide `log(n)` behavior on an average. It achieves this by keeping the indexes sorted and then applying the `binary search` (It actually uses a `tree structure` where node contains some subset of data but for understanding let us stick to it).
So, basically binary search is the one which leads to `log(n)` time but there should be something to search for. In your case there is nothing specified in the where clause, so what should it search for? It will have to read the whole index and eventually the whole table.
You can try providing `hint` but it might increase the query time and you can easily see why Oracle is not using your indexes.

ii) `Cardinality (Selectivity)` of the data but i do not think that is the issue here.